# Class file template not showing for asp.net core in visual studio 2019 16.11.4 version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, .net-core

when I use to create a console application in visual studio 2019, when I add a new file it showing class template add a new file,
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaoER.png)

but when I try to create a web application in the core, it's not giving an option of class creation...
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FsV3.png)

thanks!

Comment: Well, it looks like your VS is correctly set up since the ASP.NET Core project is correctly parsed. I'd suggest you to open the Visual Studio Installer and from there run Repair. Otherwise, edit the installation to remove .net core and add it again

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you!